# Can QuickBooks Online be used as merchant account while authorize.net is used as payment gateway?

Tags: quickbooks, authorize.net, quickbooks-online

Our client has QuickBooks Online, and our platform supports only Authorize.Net as payment gateway. We don't want to write code from scratch, plus a merchant account is needed anyways, so can we use QuickBooks Online as merchant while Authorize.Net is used as payment gateway? 
If yes, what are the steps?

Answer (score 0):

The question you're asking is akin to asking something like:

> Can I use an onion as my car?

i.e. Your question doesn't make any sense.

QuickBooks Online is not a payment gateway, and it's not a merchant account. In fact, it has nothing to do with charging credit cards what-so-ever. It's an online accounting software. It doesn't charge credit cards.

Your client might be using Intuit Merchant Services (a payment gateway/merchant account) from within QuickBooks Online though. However, that's a separate service, and it's not Authorize.net compatible - you'd have to write some new code to support it.

Comment: You can get an intuit merchant account that will work with an authorize.net payment gateway